# Image is not displaying for simple-captcha in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

The image is not displaying for Grails [`simple-captcha`](https://grails.org/plugin/simple-captcha) plugin.
While printing params.captcha in controller null value is printed.

What might be the solution? I would be thankful if anyone mention steps to integrate `simple-captcha` plugin in Grails 2.3.3. My GSP page code is:

```
<g:form controller="user" action="register">
    <g:textField name="email" placeholder="email"/><br>
    <g:passwordField name="password" placeholder="password"/><br>
    <img src="${createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'register')}"/>
    <label for="captcha">Type the letters above in the box below:</label>
    <g:textField name="captcha"/>
    <g:actionSubmit value="register" action="register" /><br>
</g:form>
```

Comment: Can't find the problem yet, but in controller try printing all the params `println params` to see if it's there. maybe you had a typo or sth..

Comment: plus the image src is **definately wrong**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong URL. Change

```
<img src="${createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'register')}"/>
```

to

```
<img src="${createLink(controller: 'simpleCaptcha', action: 'captcha')}"/>
```

Now, your image will be displayed and you can enter captcha and submit the form. In `register` action of your `user` controller, you will now see `params.captcha`.